# gitolite authentication failure

Tags: git, ssh, gitolite, atlassian-sourcetree

I've created a gitolite git on an Ubuntu server. I configured my Linux user as the administrator of the gitolite-admin project. From 3 different machines I was able to clone the repository with no problem using my private key. 
On my own machine I keep on getting "authentication via SSH keys failed".
I am using pageant. I re-installed source tree and pageant but still get the same result. I am able to connect with SSH (putty and winscp) to my user on the server, using my private key with pageant.
All machines are win 7 and running the same source-tree version 1.6.11.0.
Any ideas how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

This could help you:

1. Go to your pageant and remove all keys.
2. Close pageant service in toolbar.
3. Go in SourceTree Tools->Create or Import SSH Keys and generate a key using this selected options:
   SSH-2 RSA
4. After generated the key, put Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file as admin ssh key in your gitolite server in Ubuntu. For example this key look like this:

   ```
   ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIEAik5zoya1WgnLWZrypzYEX3cTk+1K/ZhKLWNhLcsck1ixFtWwd78Pk/ElQxcUhnICBz6yZwovUcRlk8VdL3jsDHx95yuMeZW9UnWEdaHzUOwf98Zqarsl64JqgsVFRh79MnqE46LokNAmGdtD0uP3fNfY468oHktfD2AKTGD4Or8= rsa-key-20141126
   ```
5. Save public and private key in a your machine.
6. Go to SourceTree Tools->Options and set the private ssh key path. This path is the same where you save the ssh key in step 5.
7. In SourceTree go to Tools->Launch SSH Agent...
8. The system ask you for your passphrase.
9. Enter a passphrase and after try to clone the repo using the following url:

   git@ip-server:repository-name
10. Thats all.